# Why is my PWM unstable and doesn't reach 0?

Tags: pwm, signal

I have a problem with my PWM. I have a simple circuit shown below; my command is in blue.

I aim to obtain PWM with the command in blue, but as we can observe in my figure below, when command is almost 0, the yellow curve doesn't reach 0; there is no steady state but an
unstable signal.

Does anyone have an idea of why this happens and how to improve it?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNoHZm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Edit:
I changed the N-channel MOSFET of the CMOS and I obtained this figure below, however I still have spikes.

[image]

Comment: What are your actual power supply voltages and what are your input logic levels?

Comment: My supply voltage is a 10v flyback  and my command is a siglent pwm generator

Comment: What do you mean by "10v flyback"? Why does your circuit indicate 1 volt? Should there be an inductor and capacitor in your circuit i.e. some flyback elements?

Comment: Vgs of [that FET](https://datasheet.octopart.com/VP2106N3-G-Microchip-datasheet-27836327.pdf) could be as high as -3.5 V; what does the gate signal look like?  You probably have insufficient drive or noise somewhere, but it is impossible to tell from the provided information.

Comment: What's the Vgsth of your MOSFETs?

Comment: My FLyback is composed of inductors and capacitor to filter the signal @Andy aka, the gate signal has a good shape, but I suspect a broken nmos in the circuit.

Comment: Vgsth is between 0.8v  and 3v

Comment: Did you repeat the tests with the post totem pole is not present?

Comment: Ancilarily, a Vgs threshold of -3V does not imply that it will be fully "on" if given -3.3V lets say.  The guaranteed -3V figure creates 1mA on drain, so -3.3V could be perhaps 2mA.  But R1 is 4kΩ, and if supplied 10V that's 2.5mA; R1 wins.  If supplied 5V it should be ok, but careful attention should be made to what it is actually doing.

Comment: The problem comes from a broken mosfet, but still have spike, I edited the post.

Comment: Try placing a 10nF ceramic or polypropylene capacitor right across 10 V and GND at the input of this section.  Could the load be doing anything "funny" to cause these spikes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test it with direct dc battery power source and see if there is any change

And also check if your pwm has some small spikes. If it has it will make the circuit to oscillate

[image: 1]

[image: 2]